# Generate and view macOS system performance report

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, mojave, performance

I want to generate a system performance report for my Mac. I would like that this report have CPU, Memory, disk and network activity statistics over a time period.

Like, I start the report generation in the morning morning and turn it off on the end of the day, or choose to record for an entire week.

This way, I wish to show to my boss that most of the time, my Mac runs at almost its maximum capacity. I have real data to backup my necessity of a new one.

I am looking for an app that can let me do so. If it is possible, I would appreciate a free one, but if there are no options, a paid one would also work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**iStat Menus**](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) can record up to 30 days of CPU utilisation, load average, memory pressure, memory usage, swap usage, disk usage and network upload/download rates, among others.

[image]